# Singup/Registration page for Xamarin.Forms UWP & Android

Tags: c#, android, authentication, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to create a signup/registration page for my Xamarin.Forms app. I've done a fair bit of reading on this and I've learned that authentication is a complicated process so it's best to use a service like OAuth or Azure Active Directory. I even created an account with Azure and connected my app (I think) but the documentation is sparse as far as implementing a registration page. OAuth seemed to have a pretty good tutorial on their site but it was only for Android and iOS, and my app is for Android & UWP. Is there anyone that can show how to implement a registration page in Xamarin.Forms? I don't have much of a user base yet so I'd like to use a service that's free or very cost effective, maybe like a pay per user model.

After connecting my Azure project in Visual Studio this code was auto-generated in a file called *Startup.Auth.cs*:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:MetadataAddress"],
            });
    }
}
```

And this file Startup.MobileApp.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());

        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to work with these. What I do know is how to make a page with xaml and work with user inputs in the code behind (C#), but once I have user input like a new user name and such how do I connect to the authentication service? Any help would be appreciated, either in the form of detailed instructions or a link to a tutorial. Also I am not looking to use a 3rd party login such as login with Google or login with Facebook.

Comment: do you want to use Azure AD or OAuth?  OAuth is a standard, not a specific service.   "OAuth seemed to have a pretty good tutorial on their site" - where is the link for this?  Your question as written is incredibly broad

Comment: Have a look at this repository [link](https://github.com/arditmezini/api-core).It uses JWT authentification with Asp.Net Core and Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Jason I was trying to use Azure but my impression is that Microsoft is in a transitional state with their services. They've admitted themselves that data syncing is overly complicated at present, so I'm definitely open to using an alternate service.